# What class file to create for a link model used for many to many relasionship in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have 2 models: a and b

I want to build a many to many relashionship and I will use the link model method, thus I need to create an a_to_b_membership model.

The question is:

Should I put the model class on the a model file?
The b model file? 
Or create a new model file?

If I need to create a new model file, then how should I name it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes absolutely no difference.

Firstly, however, you should realize that there's no need to have a separate file for each model. It's perfectly normal to have several model classes in one models.py file. The division is between separate apps, each of which group together related models.

Secondly, you should also realize that unless you have a specific need to add extra data on the many-to-many relationship, you don't need to create a link table. Django will take care of that for you once you define a ManyToManyField.

Comment: Who said anything about Django?

Comment: Fair answer but only a small thing. I am not using Django and I need the link model method over the key list method. 
I am using files per model because I am accustomed to this. Is it a bad idea? I use this in order to keep code cleaner to my eye-site at least. That is why I asked where to put the 3rd class.

Comment: it is not a bad idea, it's just not required even if you use python and not django. you could create a models.py file and keep object definitions logically grouped (all models on a file, all views on a file and so on). as Daniel said, it's completely up to you. If you want to stick with your initial design, you could create a 3rd file-class for your m2m relationship and import classes needed from a.py and b.py (or the naming you used).

Comment: Oops, sorry, thought this was a Django question.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I don't like having a big file that I need to search for model classes, especially when I am using my laptop. So I prefer to keep the files per model, something like an indexing for me. 

Thank you both guys for the help and the advice.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo Also how is it possible to have more than one view in the same file?

Comment: def view_one(), def view_two(), from views_file import *, then you can use view_one or view_two as you like